# How do I write this function as an extension of Dictionary

Tags: swift

I have a working function that I would rather write as an extension to dictionary using a where clause. When I use the where clause though, I lose access to the enumerated() method.

My working function:

```
func trueKeys(dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [String:Bool] {
        var trueKeys = [String:Bool]()
        dictionary.enumerated().forEach({ trueKeys[$1.key] = true })
        return trueKeys
    }
```

My goal accomplishing the same thing:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: String, Value: Any {
    func trueKeysDictionary() -> [String:Bool] {
        var trueKeys = [String:Bool]()
        self.enumerated().forEach({ trueKeys[$1.key] = true })
        return trueKeys        
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Dictionary {
   func trueKeysDictionary() -> [Key: Bool] {
       var trueKeys = [Key: Bool]()
       self.keys.forEach { trueKeys[$0] = true }
       return trueKeys
   }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @Ajean: I agree with you in general. However, here is simple question with simple answer so I doubt any explanation is needed.

Comment: You're probably right in this case.  I guess just be aware that you may have answers popping up in the Low Quality Review Queue (which is what happened for this one). I don't know if it was auto-scooped or if someone actually flagged it, but it was there ... and some reviewers (improperly!) opt to delete code-only answers.